# Can I control Homekit devices via Cordova?

Tags: cordova, homekit

I am trying to control Apple Homekit devices from my Cordova-based app. I can't find any plugin or related documentation.

Is there a way to access the common database while developing in Cordova ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "Striide" Cordova plugin may get you where you want to go. IIRC they have examples on how to interface with HomeKit devices via their iBeacon interface

Comment: I looked at that already, but the iBeacon has no reference to Homekit. Even if it does help, there's no documentation on how to access those features. Striide indeed has a Homekit sample code, but it's Swift.